# Redirect all dynamic links served using https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirection, 301-redirect

So, here is the situation:

We are running a website which is powered by [Drupal](http://drupal.org). Sometime ago, it was decided that the website should be served as SSL. The settings to redirect the site from http to https was done by a guy who is not with us anymore.

I can see in the `.htaccess` file the following lines

```
#Redirect http to https
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://docs.dev.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

mydomain.com points to the root of the LAMPP server and my site is in a folder inside the webroot (docs.dev.domain.com/mysite).

Now, it has been decided that the SSL is not needed and it has to be removed and all the pages must be served via http (301 redirect).

When I do that in the .htaccess file by using the `RewriteRule` to redirect a URL (e.g. https://docs.dev.domain.com/mysite/content/book) to http when a user visits https by using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


#Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.dev.domain.com/mysite/$1 [R=301,L]
#even tried this - RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.dev.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it redirects every request on https  to http://mydomain.com/mysite/index.php (even the urls like (https://docs.dev.domain.com/mysite/content/book/1 which should ideally be redirected to its `http` counterpart).

How can I remove the https so that my dynamic URLs are served via plain http?
Sorry if this is very novice problem.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with after swapping the order in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.dev.domain.com/mysite/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```